# flex dynamically changing values between functions

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have a main mxml and 2 AS classes.In the main mxml I have a slider.I want to get the slider values in AS classes as I move the slider.

Main.MXML

```
import First;
import Second;
private var my:First;
privaate var scd:Second;
public var sd:Date; 

public function init():void {
     my = new First();
     Canvas.addChild(my.getUIComponent()); 
}

public function dateChange():Date {
    startDate.selectedDate = new Date(slider.values[0]);
    endDate.selectedDate = new Date(slider.values[1]);
    sd = new Date(slider.values[0]);
    scd.calsldr(sd); 
    return sd;                  
}

<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top">
<mx:Canvas id="Canvas" backgroundColor="#ffffff" height="600" width="100%"
            horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
</mx:Canvas>
</mx:HBox>
<flexlib:HSlider id="slider" width="100%" height="50" thumbCount="2"                     lockRegionsWhileDragging="true" allowTrackClick="true" maintainProjectionCenter="true"
                 change="dateChange();" liveDragging="true"
                 thumbSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderThumbSkin"
                 trackSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderTrackSkin"
                 trackHighlightSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderTrackHighlightSkin" />
<mx:HBox x="300" y="300" height="50">
<mx:Label text="Start Date :"/>     <mx:DateField id="startDate"/>
<mx:Label text="End Date"/>     <mx:DateField id="endDate"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

My first AS which is first.AS
 calls Second.AS

```
addChild(new Second(str) as Sprite);
```

str is a String value

i want to use the slider values in Second.AS 
   I tried using this:

```
public function calsldr(dat:Date):void {
    trace(dat);
}

private function visualization():void{ }
```

I could get the values from trace(dat)....I mean the date's as the slider changes.
How could I use this changing values in function visualization()

PLease help.

Comment: Err... why can't you call visualization( str:date ) from calsldr? Im missing something here.

Comment: How about you tell us what you're trying to accomplish doing this because I'm seeing a lot of bad practices and I have a feeling there's a very simple way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: what is the simple way.... I want to exchange the values between functions dynamically.

Comment: Go higher level than that.  What is it your trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: Can you check the Answer.....

Answer (score 0):

@J_A_X 
The Second AS is:

```
public function Second(str:String){
    name = "Second";    }
public function calsldr(dat:Date){
    trace(dat+"fu in maaka"); // As I change the slider the value is changed here  }
protected override function init():void
    {
        var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(url));
        _bar.loadURL(ldr, function():void {
        var obj:Array = JSON.decode(ldr.data as String) as Array;
        //Sorted the values based on 'str'
    var data:Data = buildData(newarr);
        visualize(data);
        _bar = null; });
    }
public function visualize(data:Data):void{
      // I want to get the dat values here when ever the slider moves
}
```